# How can I see debug info about the VS Code Cpptools extension's IntelliSense and Code Analysis?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, intellisense, code-analysis

I've setup VS Code with the [`ms-vscode.cpptools`](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode.cpptools) extension to open my C++ project and I see the IntelliSense and Code Analysis tools running. But I never see anything in my code to suggest they're working. How can I turn on or view debug output from these to see what's going on (if anything)?

[image: VS Code dialog]

Answer (score 1):

There's the `C_Cpp.loggingLevel` setting, which if you set to `"Debug"`, some messages about code analysis will be shown, but I'm not sure how helpful that'll be to you.

The Cpptools extension has a client/server architecture (the server side's code is not publicly available as far as I know), and it doesn't seem like the status messaging is very granular in terms of progress updates. See also the related client-side code in https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-cpptools/blob/main/Extension/src/LanguageServer/codeAnalysis.ts:

```js
export function RegisterCodeAnalysisNotifications(languageClient: LanguageClient): void {
    languageClient.onNotification(PublishCodeAnalysisDiagnosticsNotification, publishCodeAnalysisDiagnostics);
    languageClient.onNotification(PublishRemoveCodeAnalysisCodeActionFixesNotification, publishRemoveCodeAnalysisCodeActionFixes);
}
```